# Repeated words dont convert to positions then to its original array when punctuation is involved

Tags: python

This code allows the user to input a sentence. It then converts the words into positions. e.g bob is great bob becomes 0,1,2,0 it then converts those positions back into the original array so 0,1,2,0 becomes bob is great bob. However whenever I use punctuation on a sentence with a repeated word like bob is great bob! it prints the positions 0,1,2,0,4 and a syntax error shows saying "list index out of range". I have no idea why this code works fine with punctuation when there are no repeated words and so require help to fix this problem.

```
import re
sentence=('bob is great bob!')
punctuation=(re.findall(r"[\w'\"]+|[.,!?;:_-]", sentence))
print(punctuation)
positions = [punctuation.index(x) for x in punctuation]
print(positions)
test1=(",".join(str(i) for i in positions))
words=" ".join(sorted(set(punctuation), key=punctuation.index))
print(words)
with open('1.txt', 'w') as f:#this creates the name of the file called task 2 which will contain my data ad allows the computer to locate the fle and add in the data. The 'w' makes the file writable so i can add in my data, without it displaying an error, using f as a variable.
     f.write(str(words))
with open('2.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write(str(test1))
f.close()
openfile=('1.txt')
openfile = open(openfile, "r")
print ( openfile.read())
openfile=('2.txt')
openfile = open(openfile, "r")
print ( openfile.read())


openfile = open('1.txt', "r")

test=openfile.read()
 #print(test)

blankarray=[]

for i in test.split(" "):
     blankarray.append(i)

#print(blankarray)


openfile.close

openfile = open('2.txt', "r")

test=openfile.read()
 #print(test)

blankarray2=[]

for i in test.split(","):
     blankarray2.append(int(i))

#print(blankarray2)
openfile.close


blankstring=""

for i in range(len(blankarray2)):
     #print(i)
     blankstring=blankstring+blankarray[blankarray2[i]] + " "
print(blankstring)
```

Comment: This is hard to read - could you remove all the calls to `open()` and `input()`  etc, and replace them with hard coded strings so that, if I copy your code and run it, I get the same error that you do.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: by replacing the line `sentence=input('enter sentence')` with `sentence = "a sample sentence"`. Do similar for the lines calling `open()`

Comment: Would it be possible if when it asks for a sentence just put "bob is great bob!" then input "1.txt" when it asks for first file then "2.txt" when it asks for the second file and that should work.

Comment: You're missing the point of what I'm saying.

Comment: Would this be okay ?

Comment: I have changed it now

Comment: The problem is that it wont convert those positions back into the original array bob is great bob!